# Tamaño automático de la forma según el tamaño de la etiqueta

Tags: delphi

Estoy implementando un cuadro de mensaje personalizado como el siguiente, pero cuando intento llenar la etiqueta con mucho texto, obtengo este resultado

[image]

La plantilla que estoy usando es la siguiente:

[image]

tengo 3 paneles:

1. `PanelBody` que contiene `labelMessage` y ambos son `align:= alClient`
2. `PanelButtons` que es `align:= alBottom`
3. `PanelIcons` que es `align:= alLeft`

y en runtime modifico la propiedad `WordWrap` de `labelMessage` a `true` y modifico el tamaño de la forma para que se ajuste a la Etiqueta

```
constructor TMyForm.Create(const Msg: String);
begin
    Self.labelMessage.Caption:= Msg;
    SetFormSize;
end;

//myWidth, myHeight contienen el nuevo size 
procedure TMyForm.SetFormSize;
var
  myWidth, myHeight: Integer;
begin
  labelMessage.WordWrap:= true;
  myWidth:= labelMessage.Width + PanelIcons.Width + 10;
  myHeight:= AdvToolBarPager1.Height + labelMessage.Height + PanelButtons.Height + 10;
  MyForm.Width:= myWidth;
  MyForm.Height:= myHeight;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MyForm.Create('lorem lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... etc ...');
    MyForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

El modal se ajusta bien dependiendo del texto que le envíe, sea mucho o poco texto, pero cada vez que cierro el modal y vuelvo a presionar el botón, siempre crece del `height`

[image]
[image]
[image]

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tamaño del formulario de acuerdo con el tamaño de la etiqueta sin que crezca el `height` cada vez que cierre y abra el modal?

Referencia

[Cuadro de Mensaje Personalizado – C# & WinForms](https://rjcodeadvance.com/cuadro-de-mensaje-personalizado-c-winforms/)

Comment: Seguramente no estés liberando el formulario antes de llamarlo por segunda vez y no se reinicializan los valores, partes de los anteriores y añades 10 unidades cada vez.

Comment: @Garada te refieres dentro del OnClose o dentro del metodo donde calculo las nuevas medidad?

Comment: Por el extracto del código veo que usas una variable llamada `MyForm` y llamas al constructor desde la variable, no desde una clase `TMyForm`. Debería ser algo como `MyForm := TMyForm.Create()` y `MyForm.Release` después del `ShowModal`

Comment: @Garada de hecho no fue necesario liberar el Form, con solo crearlo era suficiente, ya funcionó, gracias

Comment: Todo lo contrario, si no lo haces la memoria no se libera y causaría pérdidas de memoria (memory leaks)

Comment: @Garada si pero no es necesario porque una vez que se cree la forma solo se destruye llegando al `end` del método donde se esta creando, si yo estuviera creando la forma desde otra clase o algo así, si tendría que liberarla